# Set Mail app as default for mail

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Send to: Mail recipient” context menu not working](https://superuser.com/questions/469400/send-to-mail-recipient-context-menu-not-working)

How can I set the Win8 mail app to be the default application opened when using "Send To.." from other programs? Currently Outlook is what opens up when I want to send a mail, I want it to be the Mail app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the start screen and search for "default"
- Select Default Programs
- Select the Mail app and then select "set as default"
  [image]